# Inputs not a sequence wth RNNs and TensorFlow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have some very basic lstm code with tensorflow and python, where my code is

`output = tf.nn.rnn(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(10), input_flattened, initial_state=tf.placeholder("float", [None, 20]))`

where my input flattened is shape `[?, 5, 22501]`

I'm getting the error `TypeError: inputs must be a sequence` on the `state` parameter of the lstm, and I'm ripping my hair out trying to find out why it is giving me this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think when you use the tf.nn.rnn function it is expecting a list of tensors and not just a single tensor.  You should unpack input in the time direction so that it is a list of tensors of shape [?, 22501].  You could also use tf.nn.dynamic_rnn which I think can handle this unpack for you.