# How do I stack a Tensorflow Dataset tensor on the second axis after a batch operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a batch of 10 images, which gives the size `(10, 224, 224, 3)`, I want to create a larger image of size `(2240, 224, 3)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(100, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(10)
```

My desired output:

```
TensorShape([2240, 224, 3])
```

If I use `tf.concatenate` I get

> ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (None, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: why not operate a reshape in the first layer of the network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tf.split()` instead and build your new image using the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(100, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(10)

ds = ds.map(lambda x: tf.concat(tf.split(x, 10, 0), axis=1))
```

output:

```
<MapDataset shapes: (None, 2240, 224, 3), types: tf.float32>
```

Comment: I'm really thankful for your answer. This unfortunately did not work for me because I had a `batch` operation before, and it gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074435/unpackunstack-an-input-placeholder-with-one-none-dimension-in-tensorflow) error. What ended up working is: `map(lambda x, y: (tf.concat(tf.split(x, 10, 0), axis=1), y)`

Comment: You can update your question with the batch operation!

Comment: Excellent idea. I edited your answer too, because you answered well given my question, which needed more info. Feel free to double check, since I changed your solution!